# Properties of the ratio of two positive sequences as it tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\underline(a)$, $\underline(b)$ be two sequences with positive terms. Assume that $a_n/b_n -> l$. If $l = \infty$, then there exists $c_2$ such that $b_n \leq c_2a_n$ for all n.

Can I use the Archimedean property or the definition of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of convergence works just fine. You can find $N$ such that
$$n>N\Rightarrow \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}>1$$
and then you only have to control $a_n$ and $b_n$ if $0\leq n\leq N$ (finitely many values of $n$).

Comment: If $0 \leq n \leq N$, how do I control $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that $b_n \leq c_2a_2$?

Comment: There are only finitely many such numbers $n$. The $N+1$ numbers $b_0/a_0$, $b_1/a_1$, ..., $b_N/a_N$ are bounded by their maximum. Let's call it $c_1$. Then $b_n/a_n\leq c_1$ for every $0\leq n\leq N$. Then define $c_2=\max(c_1,1)$ so that the inequality $b_n\leq c_2 a_n$ holds for every $n$.